# COM port opening with CreateFile(..)

Tags: c

```
hCom = CreateFile(
    "COM1",
    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    0,
    NULL,
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    0,
    NULL
);
```

I have just one COM port on my computer, but this function returns for COM1, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7 a value unless "INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE". Why is this so?

Comment: In case you are compiling with multi-byte-character support, prefix "string" literals with an `L`, like this `L"COM1"`.

Comment: If I undertand this correctly, you seem to be able to open non-existent serial ports?  Strange.  What does it say in 'Device manager'

Comment: @alk That's the wrong way round. The code is using MBCS. It's when compiling for Unicode that you use the `L` prefix. But that's clearly not the case here, because the code compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function correctly. Unless it returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, there should be an available port. Note that this might include USB ports!

Also please note that for COM port 10 and above, you need to open them with the command `\\.\\COMn`, which corresponds to the C string `\\\\.\\COMn` (where n is the 1 or 2 digits specifying the COM port number). See http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/115831.

Comment: Note that the link in this answer has suffered bit-rot, however this page now covers the details of COM ports greater than or equal to COM10.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/howto-specify-serial-ports-larger-than-com9-db9078a5-b7b6-bf00-240f-f749ebfd913e